# Where does npm store module when loading directly from github?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have found a `react-native` module I would like to use. It contains an error which prohibits the installation.
I have forked the repository and corrected the mistake.
Now I want to install my module in order to use it,  however during execution of the post installation scripts I get an error - file not found.

I have tried to find the reason for it, but the reason is quite simple, the module is not in the node_modules directory, and when npm tries to "enter" there to run the scripts, it can't find them.

I have tried to check where this is installed, but I can't.

I use `npm install <user>/<repo>` to install my module.

Comment: maybe the initial author had the missing module installed globally instead of in the package.json

Comment: When I've said that there is a missing module, I meant the one I am installing.